# Questions about KVM devices

Tags: kvm

When I read that it's a switch I automatically think it just allows quick connection without unplugging each time. What I am looking for is simultaneous use between 2 systems. Is that what these devices do or is there a sub set that I should be looking for specifically?

EDIT: To clarify what I am looking for is a device that would take the input from a controller or mouse and keyboard and then send it independently to two different devices at the same time.

I appreciate your knowledge.

Comment: AFAIK that is not a KVM switch, that sounds more like an inverse splitter to my ears

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish by sending the same input to two devices at the same time? Maybe there is something that exists for your specific requirements.

Comment: At a guess, playing two sessions of teh same game simultaneously.  Of course it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split a USB device to connect to multiple systems in hardware at the same time. The USB protocol can't work that way. KVMs work by disconnecting from one system and then reconnecting to the another.

You can use the software [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) to share your keyboard and mouse between multiple computers, when you move your mouse from one computer to the next, it will take the keyboard input with it.